# The confusing action of super().__new__ and super().__init__ in multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, superclass

Create a `son` class which has two parents:

```
class mon():
    def __new__(cls):
        print("i am in mon's new")
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self):
        print("i am in mon's init")
        super().__init__()


class far():
    def __new__(cls):
        print("i am in far's new")
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self):
        print("i am in far's init")


class son(mon,far):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Initialize the `son` class to check what happened.
`super().__init__()` in `son` class will call `__init__` method in `mon`,the `__new__` method executed before `__init__` in `mon`,`super().__new__(cls)` in `mon` ,it make the code jump into `far` class,the `__new__` method executed before `__init__` in `far`,the code jump back to `mon` to print `i am in mon's init` and jump to `far` to print `i am in far's init` ,so we get the below output.

```
son_instance = son()
i am in mon's new
i am in far's new
i am in mon's init
i am in far's init
```

issue1:

How can rewrite the three class structure to get such output as below when to initialize `son` class?

```
son_instance = son()
i am in mon's new
i am in mon's init
i am in far's new
i am in far's init
```

Delete the statement in `far` class:

```
return super().__new__(cls)
```

The whole three class is as below then:

```
class mon():
    def __new__(cls):
        print("i am in mon's new")
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self):
        print("i am in mon's init")
        super().__init__()


class far():
    def __new__(cls):
        print("i am in far's new")

class son(mon,far):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Initialize the `son` class again.

```
x=son()
i am in mon's new
i am in far's new
```

Issue2:
Why the code can't jump back to `mon` class ?Why can't get the following output?

```
x=son()
i am in mon's new
i am in far's new
i am in mon's init
```

If no `return super().__new__(cls)` in `far` class,it only take effect on `__init__` in `far` class,but there is no `__init__` method in `far` class at all,why it result in not calling `__init__` method in `mon` class?

Comment: ... first, you know you can comment on the answer, right? (editing the question to add a comment is very confusing)

Comment: • Also based on what do you claim that "if no `return super().__new__(cls)` in `far` class,it *only* take effect on `__init__` in `far` class"? Surely it's not in the Python specification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me try to answer your two questions one by one.

> How can rewrite the three class structure to get such output as below when to initialize son class?

You can't. Your code needs to create the new instance using the `__new__` methods before it can begin to initialize the instance using the `__init__` methods. If you want behavior to run in some other order, you'll need to do it somewhere else. You can't adjust the inheritance hierarchy to get it to work.

> Why the code can't jump back to mon class ?Why can't get the following output?

Your code isn't working right because `far.__new__` is broken (probably because you got slightly overzealous while deleting the `__init__` method and deleted one extra line). The `__new__` method doesn't return anything, which is equivalent to returning `None`. If a `__new__` method doesn't return an instance of the class that was being created, the `__init__` method is never called. If you fix the `__new__` method by adding back in `return super().__new__(cls)`, you'll get the output you expect.

That happens even though the `far` class doesn't have an `__init__` method itself. The outer code (`type.__call__` in this case) doesn't know the whole inheritance hierarchy and calls each function in turn. It only calls methods on the class that is being created, and it trusts that if it's appropriate, the implementation will call the parent class versions of the function. If `son.__new__` (which is inherited) returns `None` as it does when `far.__new__` is broken, then `son.__init__` won't get called the way it did when the `__new__` methods worked properly.

Here's a very approximate pure Python version of `type.call` (the actual version is implemented in C):

```
def __call__(cls, *args):   # this is in a metaclass, so I use cls instead of self
    obj = cls.__new__(*args)
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        obj.__init__(*args)
    return obj
```

There's a lot of extra stuff I left out, like how `type(obj)` lets you get the type of an existing instance, rather than creating a new type. But the behavior when it comes to regular instance creation works as shown.

You can read the full details (in C) in [the Python source code repository](https://github.com/python/cpython), if you want. The section where the C version of `type.__call__` (called `type_call`) checks if the object returned from `cls.__new__` is of the right type is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a4774f42e35861c4bb16928cffb011c2d8a285ac/Objects/typeobject.c#L1122).

Comment: ,if no return super().__new__(cls) in far class,it only take effect on __init__ in far class,but there is no __init__ method in far class at all,why it result in not calling __init__ method in mon class?

Comment: I've updated showing why no `__init__` method gets called when `__new__` returns `None` (or any other value that's not an instance of the class that was called). I've included a link directly to the C source where this is implemented.

Comment: doesn't `new` return an instance of the class where `init` returns `None`?

Comment: @CutePoison: You're misunderstanding the context. Yes, `__new__` is supposed to return an instance (and `__init__` isn't expected to return anything), but in the questioner's code (the second version), it has a bug where `far.__new__` had its `return` statement removed (probably by mistake?). That's what is causing the `__init__` methods to not be run.